# Loop UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, scrollview

I'm really need your help. I'm having problem with wrapping `UIScrollView` (loop UIScrollView).

When I scroll fast or slow with **iOS5**, it's works. but **iOS6** is not working.

I tried to fix but i still not resolve this situation.

this is a exception i got it:

> 2012-09-27 18:00:58.170 Attack[22051:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds
>   contains NaN: [nan 0; 640 480]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x61a012 0x2c8fe7e 0x619deb 0xa33a75 0xa33d1e 0x19107a1 0x1922748 0x1922c9d 0x19295ec 0x192d0e7 0x1b9589a
>   0x1b949db 0x1b9611f 0x1b98d6d 0x1b98cec 0x1b90a68 0x18fdfc2 0x18fe4a3
>   0x18dc3aa 0x18cdcf8 0x3047df9 0x3047ad0 0x58fbf5 0x58f962 0x5c0bb6
>   0x5bff44 0x5bfe1b 0x30467e3 0x3046668 0x18cb65c 0x229a 0x21a5 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I tried many ways but i can not resolve it.This is my [source code](http://www.mediafire.com/?ovnaamni7r0gu8e). Can anyone help me ? 
Many thanks !!!

Comment: Maybe if you include the source code we might be more helpful?

Comment: I'm so sorry. this is my link source code.
http://www.mediafire.com/?ovnaamni7r0gu8e